# Предупреждение  Joomla

Tags: joomla, php

В качестве движка сайта используется Joomla 1.5. После продолжительного стабильного использования выскаочило следующее сообщение:

```
Warning: assert() [function.assert]: Assertion failed in public_html/libraries/joomla/registry/format.php on line 1
```

Пожалуйста помогите понять его смысл, и что сделать чтоб оно исчезло.

Comment: а погуглить?

Comment: Конкретно по этому предупреждению гуглено и не раз. Никакой информации почему именно там и не сразу а потом. В данный момент просто срыты все ошибки и предпреждения средствами php.ini